# If I had a game on disc and I buy it from the Playstation Store, can I use the same data?

Tags: psn, infamous

I finally got a PS3 recently. I've been trying to catch up on everything I missed, so I bought inFamous a couple of days ago, but now I've discovered that it's free from the PlayStation store. So I was thinking I'd return the game and take advantage of the free offer. But if I do that, will I have to start over, or will inFamous be able to recognize its saved games and achievements from the disc?

Comment: I kinda doubt this has been tested yet. Under normal circumstances, who would really buy both a disk and a digital download of the same game for the same system? From a completely 100% untested, I-guarantee-nothing standpoint, I would think they would. Why make two different save storing methods when they can use the existing one?

Comment: @Aeo: Yeah, it is kind of a long shot. But I know people who will sell off a game when they finish it and re-buy it later when they want to play it again, so I figured somebody might have done this before. I know my Xbox couldn't find my save game when I switched from disc Psychonauts to Psychonauts from Xbox Arcade, so I could see it go either way. I might just take the plunge whenever Sony gets the PlayStation Store back up for me.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to take the risk yourself, of all the games on the PS Store being offered as a freebie, only one of them I don't have / haven't played. So that leaves me with a spare choice... so I'll try it for ya if you want to be sure when comes back up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might not like this answer, but if you didn't have a PSN account in April, you won't qualify for the freebies.  If you have only just purchased your PS3, then this will be the case, and you should just keep the disc.

On the other hand, if you do qualify for the freebies, then yes--the games should share the data.  I base this on the example of Dead Space: Extraction.  I had the game on PSN *before* I purchased Dead Space 2 Collectors Edition, which came with a copy of the game *on the disc*.  I installed Extraction from the disc, and then launched it from the disc--it shared the data from my previous PSN version of the game.

Of course, it could just be a special case with Extraction, but that would be quite unexpected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the whole back story because it didn't seem relevant to the question. I actually did have a PSN account in April. Kind of a long story, but basically, I did briefly have a PS3 a long time ago and made a PSN account for myself. I've been getting all the "Oops, we leaked your personal information" emails from Sony, so I assume I'm covered. As soon as they get the "Forgot my password" feature working (d'oh!), I plan to restore the account on this system. Good point, though.

Comment: @Chuck Alright.  I'll leave this up anyway since it might still be relevant to someone searching.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer? I don't want to delete it because it adds interesting information, but on the other hand it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Juan It certainly was an answer, given the information that was present in the question.

Comment: @Chuck I've updated the answer with some info that you might find interesting.

Comment: @Juan peep peep

Answer (score 5):

The save files DO NOT work between blu ray version and PSN store version. I have tested this myself. You must start again from scratch.

Comment: I can confirm this, really annoying.

Comment: I actually just tested myself (with inFamous), and unlike your experience, it worked perfectly. I wonder what makes the difference.

Comment: I too went ahead and got inFamous  to test and mine did not recognize any save files... Interesting that some seem to work and others not

Comment: Perhaps it is a region issue. My game saves did not work (region 1 vs. 2).

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and downloaded inFamous, so to answer about my specific case: Yes, the disc uses the same save files as game downloaded from the PlayStation Store. Not even a tiny hiccup going between them.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Payday 2 - the saves and files aren't recognised. I subscribed to PlayStation Plus and downloaded Payday 2. When PlayStation Plus expired, I bought Payday 2 on disk and my files weren't linked - I had to start all over again.