# Will both the physical and digital copies use the same data?

Tags: ps3, dc-universe-online

I have a physical copy of DC Universe Online that I got a while back. Now the game is available on the PSN Store.

My question is will both versions of the game access the same downloaded data?

I don't want to have to complete the HUGE download again and would rather just get the disc out each time I wanted to play it if not. It seems logical that it *will* use the same data but I was just wondering if someone could confirm it.

Oh and just to note I'm *not* talking about the Save game data like mentioned [**here.**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23753/if-i-had-a-game-on-disc-and-i-buy-it-from-the-playstation-store-can-i-use-the-s) I'm more interested in Game data and patches etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided for the  good of the community clear a few things from my hard drive and download  DC Universe from the Playstation Store. Sadly however it turns out (for some unknown silly reason) it doesn't access the same downloaded update data I have for my physical copy :(

The actual game launcher (from the XMB) required updating too. Then once I was on the launch screen, where it updates, it had a big long download of 14GB!

Comment: This is because the games DVD's for the console only includes the basic launch game data that was available when the game first came out back in 2010. Since then, the game has included about 10 DLC's (Issues) and 55 Major Game updates. So yeah, you're going to have to grind through that unfortunately.